# How prove this trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

Show that

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{\tanh{\left(x\dfrac{1}{n\sin^2{\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{4n}\pi\right)}}\right)}}{1+\dfrac{\tanh^2{x}}{\tan^2{\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{4n}\pi\right)}}}=\tanh{(2nx)}$$

Thank you ,This problem I take some hours,and at last I don't prove it

and  This problem is from 
[image]

This book have some same problem.all is not true? if not true,and we how find it or edit it somewhere?
[image]

[image]

Thank you  achille hui,he told me this following maybe is true,Now How prove it?

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{\dfrac{\tanh{x}}{n\sin^2{\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{4n}\pi\right)}}}{1+\dfrac{\tanh^2{x}}{\tan^2{\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{4n}\pi\right)}}}=\tanh{(2nx)}$$

Comment: Are you sure you write down the expression correctly. It fails even when $n = 1$. For $n = 1$, the L.H.S simplifies to $\displaystyle \frac{\tanh(2x)}{1+\tanh(x)^2}$ which clearly differs from R.H.S.

Comment: Thank you,This problem is from this book:Table of Integrals,series,and Products,Seventh Edition  page 39.

Comment: It is very likely the book copied it from somewhere else incorrectly. By the way, the correct expression seems to be $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 
\frac{\frac{\tanh(x)}{n\sin^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)} 
}{1 + \frac{\tanh^2 x}{\tan^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)}} = \tanh(2nx)$$ At least for $n \le 4$, the corresponding graphs match.

Comment: oh,It's very well,Thank you

Comment: The $2^{nd}$ formula also suffers from the same problem. If you replace the $\tanh(\frac{x}{\cdots})$ by $\frac{\tanh x}{\cdots}$, then the graphs matches. I suspect the $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ formula are having the same sort of mistakes.

Comment: Yes,Thank you,Now How prove it this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice

$$\cosh(2nx) = T_{2n}(\cosh x)\quad\text{ and }\quad \cos(2nx) = T_{2n}(\cos x)$$

where $T_{2n}(z)$ is a 
[Chebyshev polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind. Using the $2^{nd}$ relation above, it is clear the roots of $T_{2n}(x)$ has the
form:
$$\pm\cos(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi),\quad\text{ for } k = 0,\ldots, n-1$$

From this, we arrive following expansion of $\cosh(2n x)$:

$$\cosh(2n x ) = A \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\cosh^2 x - \cos^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)\right)$$
for some constant $A$ we don't care.
Taking logarithm, differentiate w.r.t $x$ and divide by $2n$ for both sides, we find:
$$\begin{align}
\tanh(2n x) 
= & \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{ 2\sinh x\cosh x}{\cosh^2 x - \cos^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)}\\
= & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{ \sinh x\cosh x}{\sinh^2 x + \sin^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)}\\
= & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{ \tanh x}{\tanh^2 x + \sin^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)(1 - \tanh^2 x)}\\
\\
= & {\Large \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\frac{\tanh x}{n \sin^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)}
}{1 + (\frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)} - 1 ) \tanh^2 x} }\\
\\
= & {\Large \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\frac{\tanh x}{n \sin^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)}
}{1 + \frac{\tanh^2 x}{\tan^2(\frac{2k+1}{4n}\pi)}} }\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: It's very very nice.Thank you,+1